# start animation when pressing a button

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using the CSS motion path.

when pressing a button a square will start moving on a path.

I'm trying to make it work every time I press the button, so far did not succeed.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "./App.css";

const PathStyled = styled.div`
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0.3);
  border-right: 5px solid hsl(343, 100%, 58%);
  background: hsla(343, 100%, 58%, 0.3)
    radial-gradient(
      circle,
      hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 1) 3px,
      hsl(343, 100%, 58%, 0) 3px
    );
  offset-path: ${(props) => {
    const pathStr = "path('M40,100 l" + props.x + ",0')";
    console.log(pathStr);
    return pathStr;
  }};
  animation: distance 4000ms ease-in-out;
`;

function App() {
  const PATH_X_SEG = 200;
  const PATH_Y_SEG = 0;
  // const offSetPath
  const [path, setPath] = useState({ x: 200, y: 0 });
  const [isStartAnime,setIsStartAnime] = useState(false);
  const addToSVG = () => {
    setPath({ x: path.x + PATH_X_SEG, y: path.y + PATH_Y_SEG });
  };

  const startAnimation = () => {
    // if(isStartAnime) setIsStartAnime(false) doesn't work
    setIsStartAnime(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="controls">
        <button onClick={addToSVG}>Add segment to SVG</button>
        <button onClick={startAnimation}>Start</button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div className="section-style">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 700 700">
          <path
            d={`M40,100 l${path.x},${path.y}`}
            fill="none"
            stroke="lightgrey"
          />
        </svg>

        {isStartAnime ? <PathStyled x={path.x} y={path.y} /> : ''}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Example of how it looks and does](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-kalam-ze133?file=/src/App.js)

How can i make it work every time i press it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to remove the svg and render it again.

The line you disabled is not working because the way you set the state "isStartAnime" is too fast. Between these two lines, React doesnt have time to render the component without the svg and render it again with a the whole new svg. That's why it's not working.

Instead, you can check the code below :

```js
  const [isStartAnime, setIsStartAnime] = useState(false);
  const [reset, setReset] = useState(false);

  const startAnimation = () => {
    setIsStartAnime(false);
    setReset(true);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isStartAnime && reset) setIsStartAnime(true);
  }, [isStartAnime, reset]);

  return (
    ...
  );
```